# WSO2 API Manager Publisher URL Issue

Tags: wso2-api-manager, wso2

Experts,

I have installed WS02 API Manager(3.2.0) and changed the hostname in the file ***deployment.toml*** and then onto the ***carbon console*** added the correct callback URL as per the hostname however I keep getting the error when I access the ***publisher URL***. Surprisingly the same set of changes are working when I access the ***devportal URL***

[image]

[image]

[image]

Here are the contents of the log file:

> x.x.x.x - - [16/Feb/2021:08:28:48 +0400] - 400 - - - 0.000 x.x.x.x - -
> [16/Feb/2021:08:28:48 +0400] - 400 - - - 0.000 x.x.x.x - -
> [16/Feb/2021:08:28:48 +0400] GET /publisher/error-pages?code=500
> HTTP/1.1 200 2038 https://server.domain:9443/publisher/ Mozilla/5.0
> (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)
> Chrome/88.0.4324.146 Safari/537.36 0.004 x.x.x.x - -
> [16/Feb/2021:08:28:49 +0400] GET /publisher/site/public/css/main.css
> HTTP/1.1 200 1683
> https://server.domain:9443/publisher/error-pages?code=500 Mozilla/5.0
> (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)
> Chrome/88.0.4324.146 Safari/537.36 0.001 x.x.x.x - -
> [16/Feb/2021:08:28:49 +0400] GET
> /publisher/site/public/css/draftjs.css HTTP/1.1 200 2643
> https://server.domain:9443/publisher/error-pages?code=500 Mozilla/5.0
> (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)
> Chrome/88.0.4324.146 Safari/537.36 0.001 x.x.x.x - -
> [16/Feb/2021:08:28:49 +0400] - 400 - - - 0.000 x.x.x.x - -
> [16/Feb/2021:08:28:49 +0400] - 400 - - - 0.000 x.x.x.x - -
> [16/Feb/2021:08:28:49 +0400] - 400 - - - 0.000 x.x.x.x - -
> [16/Feb/2021:08:28:49 +0400] GET
> /publisher/site/public/conf/userThemes.js HTTP/1.1 200 937
> https://server.domain:9443/publisher/error-pages?code=500 Mozilla/5.0
> (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)
> Chrome/88.0.4324.146 Safari/537.36 0.001 x.x.x.x - -
> [16/Feb/2021:08:28:49 +0400] GET
> /publisher/site/public/fonts/iconfont/material-icons.css HTTP/1.1 200
> 970 https://server.domain:9443/publisher/error-pages?code=500
> Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like
> Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.146 Safari/537.36 0.001 x.x.x.x - -
> [16/Feb/2021:08:28:49 +0400] - 400 - - - 0.000 x.x.x.x - -
> [16/Feb/2021:08:28:49 +0400] - 400 - - - 0.000 x.x.x.x - -
> [16/Feb/2021:08:28:49 +0400] - 400 - - - 0.000 x.x.x.x - -
> [16/Feb/2021:08:28:49 +0400] GET
> /publisher/site/public/fonts/iconfont/MaterialIcons.js HTTP/1.1 200
> 6703 https://server.domain:9443/publisher/error-pages?code=500
> Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like
> Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.146 Safari/537.36 0.001 x.x.x.x - -
> [16/Feb/2021:08:28:49 +0400] GET
> /publisher/site/public/conf/portalSettings.js HTTP/1.1 200 768
> https://server.domain:9443/publisher/error-pages?code=500 Mozilla/5.0
> (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)
> Chrome/88.0.4324.146 Safari/537.36 0.001 x.x.x.x - -
> [16/Feb/2021:08:28:49 +0400] - 400 - - - 0.000 x.x.x.x - -
> [16/Feb/2021:08:28:49 +0400] GET
> /publisher/services/settings/settings.js HTTP/1.1 200 402
> https://server.domain:9443/publisher/error-pages?code=500 Mozilla/5.0
> (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)
> Chrome/88.0.4324.146 Safari/537.36 0.002 x.x.x.x - -
> [16/Feb/2021:08:28:49 +0400] GET
> /publisher/site/public/dist/swaggerWorkerInit.18fbf6bebb6bb1bb3020.bundle.js
> HTTP/1.1 200 1266
> https://server.domain:9443/publisher/error-pages?code=500 Mozilla/5.0
> (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)
> Chrome/88.0.4324.146 Safari/537.36 0.002 x.x.x.x - -
> [16/Feb/2021:08:28:49 +0400] GET
> /publisher/site/public/dist/index.c9617fd7c1348411eb00.bundle.js
> HTTP/1.1 200 140960
> https://server.domain:9443/publisher/error-pages?code=500 Mozilla/5.0
> (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)
> Chrome/88.0.4324.146 Safari/537.36 0.029 x.x.x.x - -
> [16/Feb/2021:08:28:49 +0400] GET
> /publisher/site/public/dist/f4bce6a70645d2fa8334.worker.js HTTP/1.1
> 200 106523 https://server.domain:9443/publisher/error-pages?code=500
> Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like
> Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.146 Safari/537.36 0.016 x.x.x.x - -
> [16/Feb/2021:08:28:49 +0400] GET
> /publisher/site/public/images/favicon.ico HTTP/1.1 200 162098
> https://server.domain:9443/publisher/error-pages?code=500 Mozilla/5.0
> (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)
> Chrome/88.0.4324.146 Safari/537.36 0.002 x.x.x.x - -
> [16/Feb/2021:08:28:49 +0400] GET /api/am/publisher/v1/swagger.yaml
> HTTP/1.1 200 44285
> https://server.domain:9443/publisher/site/public/dist/f4bce6a70645d2fa8334.worker.js
> Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like
> Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.146 Safari/537.36 0.011 x.x.x.x - -
> [16/Feb/2021:08:28:52 +0400] GET /publisher HTTP/1.1 302 - -
> Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like
> Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.146 Safari/537.36 0.000 x.x.x.x - -
> [16/Feb/2021:08:28:52 +0400] GET /publisher/ HTTP/1.1 200 2038 -
> Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like
> Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.146 Safari/537.36 0.002 x.x.x.x - -
> [16/Feb/2021:08:28:52 +0400] GET /publisher HTTP/1.1 302 - -
> Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like
> Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.146 Safari/537.36 0.000 x.x.x.x - -
> [16/Feb/2021:08:28:52 +0400] GET /publisher/ HTTP/1.1 200 2038 -
> Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like
> Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.146 Safari/537.36 0.002 x.x.x.x - -
> [16/Feb/2021:08:28:52 +0400] GET
> /publisher/site/public/conf/userThemes.js HTTP/1.1 200 937
> https://server.domain:9443/publisher/ Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0;
> WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.146
> Safari/537.36 0.001 x.x.x.x - - [16/Feb/2021:08:28:52 +0400] GET
> /publisher/site/public/css/main.css HTTP/1.1 200 1683
> https://server.domain:9443/publisher/ Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0;
> WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.146
> Safari/537.36 0.001 x.x.x.x - - [16/Feb/2021:08:28:52 +0400] GET
> /publisher/site/public/css/draftjs.css HTTP/1.1 200 2643
> https://server.domain:9443/publisher/ Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0;
> WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.146
> Safari/537.36 0.001 x.x.x.x - - [16/Feb/2021:08:28:52 +0400] GET
> /publisher/site/public/fonts/iconfont/MaterialIcons.js HTTP/1.1 200
> 6703 https://server.domain:9443/publisher/ Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT
> 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.146 Safari/537.36 0.001 x.x.x.x - -
> [16/Feb/2021:08:28:52 +0400] GET
> /publisher/site/public/conf/portalSettings.js HTTP/1.1 200 768
> https://server.domain:9443/publisher/ Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0;
> WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.146
> Safari/537.36 0.001 x.x.x.x - - [16/Feb/2021:08:28:52 +0400] GET
> /publisher/services/settings/settings.js HTTP/1.1 200 402
> https://server.domain:9443/publisher/ Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0;
> WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.146
> Safari/537.36 0.001 x.x.x.x - - [16/Feb/2021:08:28:52 +0400] GET
> /publisher/site/public/dist/swaggerWorkerInit.18fbf6bebb6bb1bb3020.bundle.js
> HTTP/1.1 200 1266 https://server.domain:9443/publisher/ Mozilla/5.0
> (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)
> Chrome/88.0.4324.146 Safari/537.36 0.000 x.x.x.x - -
> [16/Feb/2021:08:28:52 +0400] GET
> /publisher/site/public/fonts/iconfont/material-icons.css HTTP/1.1 200
> 970 https://server.domain:9443/publisher/ Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT
> 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.146 Safari/537.36 0.001 x.x.x.x - -
> [16/Feb/2021:08:28:52 +0400] GET
> /publisher/site/public/dist/index.c9617fd7c1348411eb00.bundle.js
> HTTP/1.1 200 140960 https://server.domain:9443/publisher/ Mozilla/5.0
> (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)
> Chrome/88.0.4324.146 Safari/537.36 0.021 x.x.x.x - -
> [16/Feb/2021:08:28:52 +0400] GET /publisher/site/public/css/main.css
> HTTP/1.1 200 1683 https://server.domain:9443/publisher/ Mozilla/5.0
> (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)
> Chrome/88.0.4324.146 Safari/537.36 0.001 x.x.x.x - -
> [16/Feb/2021:08:28:52 +0400] GET
> /publisher/site/public/css/draftjs.css HTTP/1.1 200 2643
> https://server.domain:9443/publisher/ Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0;
> WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.146
> Safari/537.36 0.001 x.x.x.x - - [16/Feb/2021:08:28:52 +0400] GET
> /publisher/site/public/fonts/iconfont/material-icons.css HTTP/1.1 200
> 970 https://server.domain:9443/publisher/ Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT
> 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.146 Safari/537.36 0.001 x.x.x.x - -
> [16/Feb/2021:08:28:52 +0400] GET
> /publisher/services/settings/settings.js HTTP/1.1 200 402
> https://server.domain:9443/publisher/ Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0;
> WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.146
> Safari/537.36 0.001
> 127.0.0.1 - - [16/Feb/2021:08:28:52 +0400] GET /api/am/publisher/v1/settings HTTP/1.1 200 951 - Jakarta
> Commons-HttpClient/3.1 0.102 x.x.x.x - - [16/Feb/2021:08:28:52 +0400]
> GET /publisher/services/auth/login HTTP/1.1 302 -
> https://server.domain:9443/publisher/ Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0;
> WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.146
> Safari/537.36 0.207 x.x.x.x - - [16/Feb/2021:08:28:52 +0400] GET
> /oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=lRyZkvkn6xjJPKNHEHV2rzbbxMoa&scope=apim:api_create%20apim:api_delete%20apim:api_import_export%20apim:api_product_import_export%20apim:api_publish%20apim:api_view%20apim:app_import_export%20apim:client_certificates_add%20apim:client_certificates_update%20apim:client_certificates_view%20apim:document_create%20apim:document_manage%20apim:ep_certificates_add%20apim:ep_certificates_update%20apim:ep_certificates_view%20apim:external_services_discover%20apim:mediation_policy_create%20apim:mediation_policy_manage%20apim:mediation_policy_view%20apim:pub_alert_manage%20apim:publisher_settings%20apim:shared_scope_manage%20apim:subscription_block%20apim:subscription_view%20apim:threat_protection_policy_create%20apim:threat_protection_policy_manage%20openid&state=/&redirect_uri=https://server.domain:9443/publisher/services/auth/callback/login HTTP/1.1 302 - https://server.domain:9443/publisher/ Mozilla/5.0
> (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)
> Chrome/88.0.4324.146 Safari/537.36 0.030
> 127.0.0.1 - - [16/Feb/2021:08:28:53 +0400] POST /oauth2/token HTTP/1.1 401 78 - Jakarta Commons-HttpClient/3.1 0.002 x.x.x.x - -
> [16/Feb/2021:08:28:53 +0400] GET
> /publisher/services/auth/callback/login?code=8da1910e-8d9c-34c7-9dd5-85b4b71376e9&state=%2F&session_state=a63045fa9041b368c460f72a1426c0beebd9279e7786b7f1da6b6c2751400fa6.zaj0baWyy-_bDDlfAF8kig
> HTTP/1.1 302 - https://server.domain:9443/publisher/ Mozilla/5.0
> (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)
> Chrome/88.0.4324.146 Safari/537.36 0.012 x.x.x.x - -
> [16/Feb/2021:08:28:53 +0400] GET /publisher/error-pages?code=500
> HTTP/1.1 200 2038 https://server.domain:9443/publisher/ Mozilla/5.0
> (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)
> Chrome/88.0.4324.146 Safari/537.36 0.001 x.x.x.x - -
> [16/Feb/2021:08:28:53 +0400] GET
> /publisher/site/public/fonts/iconfont/material-icons.css HTTP/1.1 200
> 970 https://server.domain:9443/publisher/error-pages?code=500
> Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like
> Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.146 Safari/537.36 0.001 x.x.x.x - -
> [16/Feb/2021:08:28:53 +0400] GET
> /publisher/services/settings/settings.js HTTP/1.1 200 402
> https://server.domain:9443/publisher/error-pages?code=500 Mozilla/5.0
> (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)
> Chrome/88.0.4324.146 Safari/537.36 0.003 x.x.x.x - -
> [16/Feb/2021:08:28:53 +0400] GET
> /publisher/site/public/dist/f4bce6a70645d2fa8334.worker.js HTTP/1.1
> 200 106523 https://server.domain:9443/publisher/error-pages?code=500
> Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like
> Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.146 Safari/537.36 0.017 x.x.x.x - -
> [16/Feb/2021:08:28:53 +0400] GET /api/am/publisher/v1/swagger.yaml
> HTTP/1.1 200 44285
> https://server.domain:9443/publisher/site/public/dist/f4bce6a70645d2fa8334.worker.js
> Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like
> Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.146 Safari/537.36 0.010

Comment: Could you please share the error logs ?

Answer (score 0):

When updating the callback URLs follow the documentation[1] and make sure you have updated it correctly

[1] https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/troubleshooting/troubleshooting-invalid-callback-error/

Comment: yes its exactly the way mentioned in this doc